# How to get related rows of spatie/laravel-tags object?

Tags: laravel-5, tags

I added spatie/laravel-tags plugin https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/basic-usage/using-tags
to my Laravel 5.7 app and added it in one of my models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
...
use \Spatie\Tags\HasTags;

class Vote extends MyAppModel
{
    use HasTags;


    protected $table = 'votes';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    ...
```

I succesfully added some data in my init seeders, but I did not find how can I retrieve list of related tags
of vote object:

```
$vote           = Vote::find($vote_id);
$relatedTags    = $vote::Tags([])->get(); // That fails
```

MODIFIED BLOCK:

1) I want to add some inin data in my seeder database/seeds/votesInitData.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Vote;
use \Spatie\Tags\HasTags;

class votesInitData extends Seeder
{
    use HasTags;
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        $lNewVote= Vote::create([
            'id'               => 1,
            'name'             => 'Question?',
            'slug'             => 'question',
            'description'      => 'Still ...',
            'creator_id'       => 3,
            'vote_category_id' => 1,   
            'is_quiz'          => false,
            'is_homepage'    Call to undefined method App\Tag::findOrCreate()
  => true,
            'ordering'         => 1,
            'status'           => 'A',
            'image'            => 'tobe.png',
//            'tags'             => ['Hamlet', 'William Shakespeare', 'Drama', ' William Shakespeare '],
        ]);
        $tagWithType = Tag::findOrCreate('headline', 'newsTagType');
        $lNewVote->attachTag($tagWithType);
```

and I got error:

```
: Class 'Tag' not found
```

Did I miss to include some more declaration ? I included HasTags .

2) This

```
   $activeTag = Tag::where('slug', $tag_slug)->first();
```

does not work, as I see in sql-tracing :

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `tags` 
    WHERE `slug` = 'thriller' limit 1
```

But looking at tags table I see that tags table has content

```
name : {"en": "Steven Spielberg"}
slug : {"en": "steven-spielberg"}
```

so nothing is found!

Which is the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to call `$vote->tags;` to receive all associated tags

Comment: Thank you!
I see that tags tables also has "type" field.
I fill my data with code like :
$newsItem = NewsItem::create([
   'name' => 'testModel',
   'tags' => ['tag', 'tag2'], //tags will be created if they don't exist
]);
But I did not find how adding new tags assign some type for them ?

Comment: I did not find if there is a method to searcg by slug, like :
        $activeTag = Tag::findBySlug( $tag_slug );
?

Comment: You have to create the `tag ` with the type and then attach it to the model with `attachTag()`.
See here: https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/advanced-usage/using-types

Comment: I did not find a method to retrieve a tag by slug but you could just use:  `Tag::where('slug', $tag_slug)->first();`

Comment: Remul, Thank you for your feedback!
Please, look at MODIFIED block

Comment: `HasTags` is just a trait for models that adds methods to interact with tags, remove that from your seeder. Import the model instead with `use Spatie\Tags\Tag`.

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED # 2 BLOCK, I have one more question.

Comment: Could you open a new question if you have additional questions.

Comment: Done, under this btanch.

Comment: I meant a completely new question, you posted your question as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should add Tag class to config file with :
`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Tags\TagsServiceProvider" --tag="tags-config"`

and the end of is enough to call bay name : `Tag::where('slug', $tag_slug)->first()->name;`